# What is Two Way (2-way) data binding in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, eval, bind, 2-way-object-databinding

What is 2-way data binding in ASP.NET. I heard `Bind()` is two way data binding approach.

How it is different from `databinder.eval` or `Eval()`?

What is the advantage of 2-way databind and in what kind of situation one should go for 2-way data binding and use `Bind()` instead of `databinder.eval()`?

Please, discuss in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For read-only values such as Labels you can use the Eval() statement, and for read-write values such as TextBoxes (also known as "two-way databinding") you can use the Bind() statement

Comment: we can also bind TextBoxes with DataBinder.Eval(). so why Bind() is required. what is the advantage of Bind(). plzz explain. thanks

Comment: you can bind textbox with eval but for read only, if you want that the update/insert will work you will use bind.